# integrating road signs in Here maps

Tags: reactjs, maps, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Hi I am new to React and Here maps, I am using Here maps for maps. Currently I am able to show live marker position, I want to show road signs as well.

For that I am constructing a request as specified here [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/dev_guide/topics/resource-roadsign.html)

```
https://image.maps.ls.hereapi.com/mia/1.6/roadsign?apiKey=H6XyiCT0w1t9GgTjqhRXxDMrVj9h78ya3NuxlwM7XUs&region=USA&category=0&label=I-80&w=100&h=100&f=0
```

In the documentation , only highways signs are mentioned. Is it possible to query traffic,speed limit signs as well? And the response returns image(PNG) , I am thinking to put that image onto map at specific lat and long position. Is this the right way to do?

Comment: It's not adviseable to post your API keys.

Comment: That is not my API key. That is the key which is given in Here Maps website for quick tests

Answer (score 0):

The roadsign feature of the Map Image API has a very limited selection of signs and is in maintenance. You will have to create or source these images yourself. Fortunately there are many free icon collections available on the web.

Once you have the images, you can use a MapMarker to place these on the map.